# How to add types to Cypress.env?

Tags: javascript, typescript, testing, cypress, intellisense

I have this `cypress.json` config file:

```json
{
  "env": {
    "example": "Hello World!"
  }
}
```

In my tests:

```
Cypress.env("example")
```

Can I add any kind of type defintion to the env system? (to work with Typescript or eslint) I would love to use intellisense here.

Answer (score 8):

From cypress.d.ts

```js
interface Cypress {
  /**
   * Returns specific environment variable or undefined
   * @see https://on.cypress.io/env
   * @example
   *    // cypress.json
   *    { "env": { "foo": "bar" } }
   *    Cypress.env("foo") // => bar
  */
  env(key: string): any
}
```

so you can extend it with

```js
declare namespace Cypress {
  interface Cypress {
    env(key: "example"): string
  }
}
```

which gives intellisense `(method) Cypress.Cypress.env(key: "example"): string (+6 overloads)`

Comment: This is the right direction! It accepts wrong values but gives intellisense which is quite helpful.

Comment: You might be able to add a new type that constrains `string` to specific string values, and use that as return type in the extension.

Comment: You can export eg. ConfigEnv from `cypress.config.ts` like typeof config.env. Then you can extend Cypress and define env in `cypress.d.ts` as suggested like: `env<T extends keyof ConfigEnv>(key: T): ConfigEnv[T];` It will suggests only defined env variables and also inherits correct types for them.

Answer (score -1):

According to [documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/env#Syntax):

```
    Cypress.env("myOwnTypeKey", {
        value: "yourOwnKey",
        type: "myOwnTypeClass"
    });
```

should set a specific variable with *myOwnTypeKey*.
Then you could check if the "yourOwnKey" with a call to instanceof "myOwnTypeClass".

Value could be a complex [object](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/env#Object) as well.

Comment: How is this related to my question? Do you mean since there is no definition about this in their docs they don't support any types safety there?

Comment: You asked "Can I add any kind of type defintion to the env system", then the above is how you can add any kind of object/variable with specific value

Comment: Alright. So you don't know about type safety?

Comment: Since is a .json file you can't have more than the json types definition.
You could use a trick as above edit to achieve a sort of type safety.